# return response in a function in express app

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

As we know, we must return the response in the express app to avoid *"Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client"* error.
However, In below code, I'm trying to return the response but It's returning to our router and causes mentioned error. how I can directly return the response in function?

```
router.post("/admins", async function (req, res) {

    var newAdminObj = await newAdminObjectDecorator(req.body, res);

    var newAdmin = new Admins(newAdminObj)

    newAdmin.save(function (err, saveresult) {
        if (err) {
            return res.status(500).send();
        }
        else {
            return res.status(200).send();
        }
    });
});



// the function
var newAdminObjectDecorator = async function (entery, res) {

    // doing some kinds of stuff in here

    // if has errors return response with error code
    if (err) {
        // app continues after returning the error header response
        return res.status(500).send();
    }
    else {
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Simply throw an error instead of res.status(500).send

Comment: Thank you, but is it the best practice? could you explain more (as an answer) about the throw and other ways to solve this problem, if exist?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Never run a response operation other than the controller's functions. Let the other function return the answer and decide according to the answer.

```
router.post("/admins", async function (req, res) {

    var newAdminObj = await newAdminObjectDecorator(req.body);

    if (newAdminObj instanceof Error) {
        return res.status(500).send()
    }

    var newAdmin = new Admins(newAdminObj)

    newAdmin.save(function (err, saveresult) {
        if (err) {
            return res.status(500).send();
        }
        else {
            return res.status(200).send();
        }
    });
});



// the function
var newAdminObjectDecorator = async function (entery) {

    // doing some kinds of stuff in here

    // if has errors return response with error code
    if (err) {
        // app continues after returning the error header response
        return err;
    }
    else {
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Teşekkür ederim.